# How to fix yyyy is not a function when changing pages in Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app that uses Videojs plugin to add markers on video. Everything works, except when going from one page to another, I get the error: ***player.markers is not a function.*** It works again only if I refresh the page.

To explain better, when I first time enter the webpage, or if page is already opened and refresh it, then everything works. However, If I go to page 2, I get the ***player.markers is not a function*** error. Also, If I refresh the page, it works again.

I know it should be simple to fix, somewhere the plugin is not loaded when going from one page to another, but I cannot find the solution.

Here is my code:

Controllers:

```
// ********  CONTROLLER 1 *********
app.controller('topicCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    //bookmarks list. here is also data about markers on video progress bar
    $scope.markers = [
    {
        time: 9.5,
        text: "Compare Balance",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 106,
        text: "xRay Rules",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 43.6,
        text: "Rule filter0-text",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 78,
        text: "Using help-id class",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    }];

    //video player object
    var player = videojs('myVideo');

    //load the marker plugin
    //!!! HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR. player.markers not a function
    player.markers({
        markers: $scope.markers,
        markerStyle: {
            'width': '17px',
            'border-radius': '30%',
            'background-color': 'green'
        },
        markerTip:{
            display: true,
            text: function(marker) {
                return marker.text;
           },
            time: function(marker) {
                return marker.time;
            }
        },
         onMarkerClick: function(marker) {}
    });
});

// ********  CONTROLLER 2 *********
app.controller('devCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $window) {

    //bookmarks list. here is also data about markers on video progress bar
    $scope.markers = [
    {
        time: 9.5,
        text: "Compare Balance",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 106,
        text: "xRay Rules",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 43.6,
        text: "Rule filter0-text",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    },
    {
        time: 78,
        text: "Using help-id class",
        overlayText: 'overlay'
    }];

    //video player object
    var devPlayer = videojs('myVideo');

    //load the marker plugin
    devPlayer.markers({
        markers: [],
        markerStyle: {
            'width': '17px',
            'border-radius': '30%',
            'background-color': 'green'
        },
        markerTip:{
            display: true,
            text: function(marker) {
                return marker.text;
            },
            time: function(marker) {
                return marker.time;
            }
        },
        onMarkerClick: function(marker) {}
    });
})
```

HTML

```
<!- ***** page 1 ***** -->
    <div id="page">
        <h2>Page 1 {{title}}</h2>

        <div id="videoContainer">
            <video id = "myVideo" width="600" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
                <source src="videos/xray-stable-ids.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>

            <bookmark-list></bookmark-list>
        </div>
    </div>

<!- ***** page 2 ***** -->
    <div id="page">
        <h2>Page 2 {{title}}</h2>

        <div id="videoContainer">
            <video id = "myVideo" width="600" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls>
                <source src="videos/xray-stable-ids.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>

            <bookmark-list></bookmark-list>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also tried to watch for route change, and tried to load the full page but no luck.

HERE is my plunker. Notice, when you change between pages, you get player.markers not a function. I need to understand why I get that on page change.  https://plnkr.co/edit/OfbJEpgZiGdbXwF3kNE0?p=preview

Comment: please, provide [plunker](http://plnkr.co) example

Comment: @GProst Hi, I added the plunker link. You will see in the console, the 'is not a function' error which causes me problems

Answer (score 0):

When you first call `videojs('myVideo')` it returns object with **method (function)** called `markers`. When you call it, it returns **object** with properties/methods `add`, `destroy`, `getMarkers` etc. So when you call `videojs('myVideo')` each subsequent time, it returns that object. And you don't have method `markers()` anymore.

I fixed it with simple `if` statement in your controllers (**both**):

```
if (typeof devPlayer.markers === 'function') {

  devPlayer.markers({

  ...

}
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FqpIwASmhfjvXhiuCrUe?p=preview).